# GNU GRUB Version 2.04 Installed Ubuntu 20.04.01 Version

Tags: boot, grub2, bash, xubuntu, selinux

I have an ASUS TUF A15 laptop which has Ubuntu 20.04.1 Desktop installed. It was working fine. I did not use it for the last week and, starting from yesterday, when I open it, it gives me the following error:

```
GNU GRUB version 2.04
Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word,
TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists
possible device or file completions.

grub> _
```

I searched on Google and found some workaround with the parameters below and it worked:

```
set prefix=(hd0,msdos5)/boot/grub
set root=(hd0,msdos5)
insmod normal
normal
```

I was able to login with these parameters, but when I rebooted the laptop to verify that I solved the problem, it again gave me the above GNU GRUB 2.04 error. Please note that there is only Ubuntu installed on this laptop.

Appreciate your support. Can any one help me out with this error?

Comment: Can you clarify the question here?

Comment: Boot into linux again, then run `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt upgrade`, `sudo updage-grub`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I have already run (sudo update grub) command after login into system and it was successful but again it is going back to same grub page again and again.

Comment: What `sudo update-grub` output?

Comment: Thanks you for our commands it repair the grub file @HolyBlackCat